# How to move hamburger menu to the front of overlay menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

How can I move the hamburger menu in front of overlay menu whilst holding its position from mobile through to desktop? Here is an example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/EyjaZK)

Here is my code below

**HTML**

```
<nav>            
      <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box"> 
         <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
      </button>

     <div class="overlay">
        some list elements go here
     </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparentize($darkest-grey,0.01);
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;

li{
    list-style: none;
  }
}

.is-active{
    display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <script>
      var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
      var overlayMenu = document.querySelector(".overlay");
      hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
        hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
        overlayMenu.classList.toggle("is-active");
      });
 </script>
```

Also I'm using [Bourbon neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/) and [Hamburgers](https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers). If theres a more elegant way of doing this then please let me know :) Thanks!

Comment: Higher `z-index` on the `.is-active` must solve your problem but without the rest of the CSS I can't give you the exact values or properties

Comment: @daniP I have added more css. I tried adding a z-index of 9999 on the z-index yet this did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a higher `z-index` for the hamb.

> Remember z-index works just for positioned elements, you need to change the default static position of the button.

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.is-active {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze is-active" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box"> 
         <span class="hamburger-inner">button</span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <div class="overlay">
    some list elements go here
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried this but the overlay becomes contained within the grid and loses it full screen 100% width/height ability :(

Comment: @samsos the only way I can help U is with a real example on jsfiddle or codepen with your actual code

Comment: I have added a Codepen

Comment: Done the problem was the class `is-active` was on the overlay too ... just making more specific the selector like `button.is-active` and asign the z-index works. @samsos http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMpbdQ ... If this helps mark it as solved

Comment: I guess that works. Any idea how I cam get the logo to overlay and turn change colour to white aswell the 'x' icon?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113682/discussion-between-samsos-and-danip).